# Impersonation in Dynamics

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, impersonation

I can't understand what to do. I use the usual API method which is called from an Angular application from Dynamics with impersonation context.

At first I'm doing this

```
var impersonationContext = ServiceSecurityContext.Current.WindowsIdentity.Impersonate();
```

Then I'm trying to create an instance with one parameter - `OrganizationServiceProxy`, then create the `OrganizationServiceProxy`.

Then when I'm trying to retrieve from CRM base

```
public OrganizationDetailCollection DiscoverOrganizations(IDiscoveryService service)
{
    if (service == null) 
        throw new ArgumentNullException("service");

    var organizationsRequest = new RetrieveOrganizationsRequest();
    var organizationsResponse = (RetrieveOrganizationsResponse)service.Execute(organizationsRequest);

    return organizationsResponse.Details;
}
```

The code throws an exception

> System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityNegotiationException: The caller was not authenticated by the service.
>
> System.ServiceModel.FaultException: The request for security token could not be satisfied because authentication failed

But when I comment out the line with the `impersonationContext`, it works fine. Maybe someone has advice or suggestions?

Comment: Have a look at these articles: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customerengagement/on-premises/developer/org-service/impersonate-another-user?view=op-9-1 and https://powerobjects.com/crm2011/how-to-impersonate-in-microsoft-dynamics-crm/